# Attribute Assistant for 10.0 does not have AutoNumber, is there a workaround for ArcMap 10.0

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, fields-attributes

I work for a water utility division and we are using ArcMap 10.0 with attribute assistant.  In attribute assistant 10.1 and up there is a value method called AutoNumber which will auto increment and populate a field with the next highest integer.  Unfortunately this option does not seem to be available in 10.0 which is my problem.  I have located a script at

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38517

which will do this but I would like to find a better solution or one that would integrate with attribute assistant 10.0 . Is this possible and has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey user3338197 - Was the ["Generate Identifier"](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/localgovernment/10.1/index.html#/Generate_identifier/028s0000008p000000/) method available in attribute assistant for 10.0? If this is the case you may be able to use 'Generate identifier' in conjunction with an entry in the Generate ID table to achieve the desired effect - Thanks!

Comment: Generate Identifier is not available in versioned ArcMaps.  Any other ideas?